# Winged-edge vs half-edge

Tags: cad, topology, brep

I try to understand boundary representation (B-rep) and I cannot find what's the advantages of the half-edge data structure versus the winged-edge one. I've found in [this book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-45729-6) that winged-edge cannot represent the state where a vertex but no edges exists in space. But there is no sample.

[Another book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=bIoWorFdmBkC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=limitation%20of%20winged%20edge%20data%20structure&source=bl&ots=NNqg5p1ebe&sig=N-zJOcaNIGf2za453nMvQwLE_Mo&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8m_CQqobKAhUB2RQKHfnmAJgQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=limitation%20of%20winged%20edge%20data%20structure&f=false) says that there is an ambiguity in the edge direction.

And finally, on a [this web page](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Half-Edge_Data_Structure.shtml), performance reasons are invoked.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the solution in [this paper](https://www.academia.edu/4898337/An_Overview_on_Boundary_Representation_Data_Structures_for_3D_Models_Representation).

With winged-edge, you've got this data structure:

[image]

The code in C# is as follow:

```
public class WingedEdge
{
    public Curve3d Curve { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Edge of the left loop starting on the end vertex of this edge.
    /// </summary>
    public Edge EndLeftEdge { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Edge of the right loop starting on the end vertex of this edge.
    /// </summary>
    public Edge EndRightEdge { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Vertex on the end point of the edge.
    /// </summary>
    public Vertex EndVertex { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Face on the left side of the edge.
    /// </summary>
    public Face LeftFace { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Face on the right side of the edge.
    /// </summary>
    public Face RightFace { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Edge of the left loop ending on the start vertex of this edge.
    /// </summary>
    public Edge StartLeftEdge { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Edge of the right loop ending on the start vertex of this edge.
    /// </summary>
    public Edge StartRightEdge { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Vertex on the start point of the edge.
    /// </summary>
    public Vertex StartVertex { get; set; }
}
```

On the face, you only need to store one of the bounding edge, as the structure forms a double linked list, you can retrieve the other edges:

```
public class Face
{
    /// <summary>
    /// One of the edges bounding this face.
    /// </summary>
    public WingedEdge FirstEdge { get; set; }
}
```

But if you need to iterate over the edges of a face, you will use this code:

```
WingedEdge edge = face.FirstEdge;
do {
  // Do something with the edge
  WingedEdge edge = edge.LeftFace == face ? edge.LeftNextEdge : edge.RightNextEdge;
} while (edge != face.FirstEdge)
```

We have to use a conditional expression (? :) in the loop to find the next edge. On modern processors, this lead to a performance hit, as described [in this post](http://igoro.com/archive/fast-and-slow-if-statements-branch-prediction-in-modern-processors/).

The half-edge data structure has not this problem (but takes more memory).